# How to define a new \item command to produce a different color?

Tags: color, lists

I am trying to define an alternative `\item` command that would allow me to use a different color for some of the items. My code has the following form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}
\newcommand{\grayitem}[1]{{\color{gray} \item #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\grayitem Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I was hoping that

```
\grayitem Second item.
```

would produce the same result as

```
{\color{gray} \item Second item.}
```

but for some reason, these are not equivalent. They produce the following results, respectively:

[image]            [image]

Why are these two lines of code not equivalent? What am I doing wrong and how can I change the definition of `\grayitem` to produce the second result?

I have also tried removing a pair of braces, like this

```
\newcommand{\grayitem}[1]{\color{gray} \item #1}
```

but then the third item becomes gray as well.

The solution should also work for multi-paragraph items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit hacky, but without braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}


\let\olditem\item
\newcommand{\grayitem}{\color{gray}\olditem}
\renewcommand{\item}{\color{black}\olditem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\grayitem Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To make subliste adhere to the gray colour one could do something like the following, however if you want to use gray items inside a second level list, changing back to black won't work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

\makeatletter
\let\olditem\item
\newcommand{\grayitem}{\color{gray}\olditem}
\renewcommand{\item}{%
    \ifnum\@enumdepth<2
        \color{black}%
    \fi%
\olditem}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item.
    \grayitem Second item.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item bla
            \item bla
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Third item.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item bla
            \grayitem bla
            \item bla
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice approach, but bad for those with many text colors ;)

Comment: @TeXnician Too many text colours are already damned to go to the typographical hell, no hope in saving them :)

Comment: Totally right. Hence, I've also added a hacky two-color approach (probably with very bad style).

Comment: @TeXnician Nice hack :)

Comment: +1. Much appreciated. (Sadly, I cannot accept both answers.) @TeXnician: Interestingly, both hacks seem to stop working when the `\grayitem` in question contains another list. But I did ask for "everything between one `\item` and the next" in my comment =)

Comment: @DejanGovc Well the "next item" is of course the first one of the other list :)

Comment: @samcarter: Indeed, that's what I meant. I got exactly what I asked for =)

Comment: @DejanGovc Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you, this actually suits my needs perfectly, so I've reconsidered my choice of accepted answer. Also, thanks again to @TeXnician.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple: You forgot braces around your argument. You would have to use `\grayitem{Second item.}`. Else TeX uses only the first token (the "S") and the rest is not in `#1` anymore.

In fact that would be your document with right color:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}
\newcommand{\grayitem}[1]{{\color{gray}\item #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\grayitem{Second item.}
\item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

*Update:* As I was challenged (`;)`) here's another solution for items without braces using `etoolbox` in a slightly unintended manner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}
\let\olditem\item
\newcommand{\grayitem}{\let\item\olditem\color{gray}\item\preto\item{\color{black}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\grayitem Second item.
\item Third item.
\grayitem Another one.
\item Test
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right, this works. Is there a way of doing it without adding the braces? I'm asking because `\item` does not seem to require these braces and it would make it easier to switch between the two. Can `#1` be somehow forced to consist of everything between one `\item` and the next?