# LaTEX - Colors in itemize

Tags: color

By using the command

```
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\color{itemizeColor1}{$\bullet$}}
```

(where \itemizeColor a user defined color) I am able to set globally the color attributes of itemize and enumerate environments. This works well with

```
\item .......
```

but not with

```
\item [..] ....
```

Is it possible to define the color globally for the second case? Thanks

Comment: You could find this useful https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359252/how-to-define-a-new-item-command-to-produce-a-different-color?rq=1

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381486/color-an-item-in-an-enumerated-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use option `font` in `\setlist` to set the color for the itemize labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{
  font=\color{itemizeColor1},% <- added
  label=$\bullet$% <- changed
}
\colorlet{itemizeColor1}{purple}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item[$\star$] second item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]